# Need to know Class of a Byte Array saved in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, serialization, arrays, jbpm

I am stuck at strange issue.

I have a `jbpm5.3` web panel and what i am trying to do it to create web services in servlets by manipulating mysql database. i have done all the things but stuck in one byte array.
this web panel uses a table workiteminfo in which it saves all the details and uses this byte array for further processing.

My problem is that i do not have information about this byte array, but what i got to know is that this byte array is an object an unknown class.
If i have this class skeleton my problem will be solved.

Here im giving screenshot of that table,
**NULL** entries are from my code :(

http://s9.postimg.org/hbgz6kar3/issue.png

What i have tried:

1. Used random byte array [Not worked]
2. Used byte array from another row [Web Panel gone mad]
3. I can not change even a single line from web panel's code, everything need to be done at my end.

Please guys help me out, what approaches can i use to solve this issue?

Comment: The class of the object stored in the blob may very well be private, in which case you are completely out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jBPM use [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) to serialize the work item Data. It doesn't use common java serialization.

If you want to add some work items for jBpm you can launch a jBpm workflow with one UserTask or something similar.

Comment: Yeah.. finally i had to integrate jBPM within my web-services

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to do, but hey, who am I to judge you ;)
The ByteArray can't be de-serialized to any java class because it is not just 1 serialized object. In fact, it appears to be 4 or more.
As Fernando mentioned, jbpm uses protobuf to de/serialize its own state. In version 5.3, the Serializer implementation is this:

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/5.3.x/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/marshalling/impl/OutputMarshaller.java#L1067

You can see there how the writeWorkItem method is implemented.
The analogous class of OutputMarshaller is InputMarshaller:

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/5.3.x/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/marshalling/impl/InputMarshaller.java#L1132

This class contains a readWorkItem method that knows how to marshall the byte array into a [WorkItem class](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/5.3.x/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/process/instance/WorkItem.java).

The serialization is triggered from the [WorkItemInfo class](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/5.3.x/drools-persistence-jpa/src/main/java/org/drools/persistence/info/WorkItemInfo.java#L134).

One idea could be to use this class to de-serialize the whole table.

Hope it helps,