# jbpm process instance throws NPE while getting Workflowinstance variable from db

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn

Previously i have asked about jBPM's ProcessInstanceInfo and WorkItemInfo here
[Need to know Class of a Byte Array saved in MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935935/need-to-know-class-of-a-byte-array-saved-in-mysql-database)
Now i have integrated the jBPM libs into my code and everything seems to be working fine except creation of a new ProcessInstance.
When i create a new processInstance from already built WebSite, the workflow works fine if i complete a task from my code. But when i create a new Process Instance from my code it works fine on my side but throws a NullPointer on Web.

I am using following piece of code to create New Process Instance

```
    public Long startProject(ProjectDTO projectDto, UserDTO userInfo) {

    ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
            ServletContextHolder.getContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF")
                    + "/dispatcher-servlet.xml");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) context
            .getBean("sessionFactory");

    UserinfoHBM userinfoHBM = new UserinfoHBM(sessionFactory);
    WorkflowHBM workflowHBM = new WorkflowHBM(sessionFactory);

    TemplateHBM templateHBM = new TemplateHBM(sessionFactory);
    Template template = templateHBM.getTemplateById(Integer
            .parseInt(projectDto.getTemplateId()));

    Map<String, Object> processData = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    processData.put("Initiator", userInfo.getUsername());
    UserInfo userInfoReq = userinfoHBM.getUserById(Integer
            .parseInt(userInfo.getRequester()));
    processData.put("Requester", userInfoReq.getFirst_name());
    List<String> requesterEmail = new ArrayList<String>();
    requesterEmail.add(userInfoReq.getEmail());
    processData.put("RequesterEmail", requesterEmail);
    UserInfo userInfoSup = userinfoHBM.getUserById(Integer
            .parseInt(userInfo.getSupplier()));
    processData.put("Supplier", userInfoSup.getFirst_name());
    List<String> supplierEmail = new ArrayList<String>();
    supplierEmail.add(userInfoSup.getEmail());
    processData.put("SupplierEmail", supplierEmail);
    UserInfo userInfoMan = userinfoHBM.getUserById(Integer
            .parseInt(userInfo.getManager()));
    processData.put("Manager", userInfoMan.getFirst_name());
    List<String> managerEmail = new ArrayList<String>();
    managerEmail.add(userInfoMan.getEmail());
    processData.put("ManagerEmail", managerEmail);
    List<String> initiatorEmail = new ArrayList<String>();
    initiatorEmail.add(userInfo.getEmail());

    processData.put("initiatorEmail", initiatorEmail);
    Workflow workflow = workflowHBM.getWorkflow(template.getWorkflow()
            .getWorkflow_id());

    Long processId = startProcess(workflow, processData,
            userInfo.getUsername(), projectDto.getName(),
            projectDto.getUniqueProjectRefId());

    return processId;

}
```

AND

```
    public Long startProcess(Workflow workflow,
        Map<String, Object> processData, String userName,
        String project_name, String uniqueProRefNo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Long processId = new Long(0);
    try {
        Boolean status = false;
        Map<String, String> taskTypeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, ProcessTaskData> processTaskDataMap = new HashMap<String, ProcessTaskData>();
        Map<String, WorkflowTask> workflowTaskMap = new HashMap<String, WorkflowTask>();
        for (WorkflowTask workflowTask : workflow.getWorkflow_taskList()) {
            ProcessTaskData processTaskData = new ProcessTaskData();
            processTaskData.setProjectName(project_name);
            processTaskData.setProjectUniNumber(uniqueProRefNo);
            processTaskData.setTaskType(workflowTask.getTask_type());

            processTaskData.setTaskId(workflowTask.getTask_id());

            // processTaskData.setAssign(" User/Group Name");
            processTaskData.setSubassign(workflowTask
                    .getDianamicAssimentGroup());

            taskTypeMap.put(workflowTask.getTask_name(),
                    workflowTask.getTask_type());

            if (workflowTask.getTask_type().equalsIgnoreCase("survey")) {
                List<String> email = new ArrayList<String>();
                email.add(workflowTask.getSendSurveyToemail());
                processTaskData.setSurveyEmail(email);
            }
            processTaskDataMap.put(workflowTask.getTask_name(),
                    processTaskData);

            if ("parallel".equalsIgnoreCase(workflowTask.getTask_Mode())) {

                workflowTaskMap.put(workflowTask.getTask_name(),
                        workflowTask);
            }
            if (workflowTask.getTask_type().equalsIgnoreCase("approve")) {
                status = true;
            }
            if (workflowTask.getTask_type().equalsIgnoreCase("survey")) {
                List<String> email = new ArrayList<String>();
                email.add(workflowTask.getSendSurveyToemail());
                processTaskData.setSurveyId(workflowTask.getSurveyForm()
                        .getSurve_from_Id());
                processTaskData.setSurveyEmail(email);
            }
            if (workflowTask.getTask_type().equalsIgnoreCase("email")) {
                List<String> email = new ArrayList<String>();
                // email.add();
                List<EmailListsItems> items = workflowTask
                        .getEmailListsItems();
                for (EmailListsItems e : items) {
                    email.add(e.getName());
                }
                processTaskData.setEmailList_EmailTask(email);
            }
            // workflowTaskMap

        }

        UserTransaction ut = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext()
                .lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
        ut.begin();

        StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = JbpmAPIUtil.getSession();

        processData.put("workflowTaskMap", workflowTaskMap);
        processData.put("taskTypeMap", taskTypeMap);
        processData.put("formComments", new ArrayList<String>());
        processData.put("processTaskDataMap", processTaskDataMap);
        processData.put("rejectStatus", true);

        ProjectFormData projectFormData = new ProjectFormData();
        projectFormData.setProjectFormDataMap(new HashMap());
        projectFormData.setProjectFormTableMap(new HashMap());
        projectFormData.setProjectSurveyFormMap(new HashMap());

        processData.put("projectFormData", projectFormData);
        CommandBasedWSHumanTaskHandler taskHandler = new CommandBasedWSHumanTaskHandler(
                ksession);
        ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task",
                taskHandler);

        /*
         * JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger logger2 = new
         * JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger(ksession);
         */

        ProcessInstance instance = ksession.startProcess(workflow
                .getWorkflow_name().replaceAll(" ", ""), processData);

        processId = instance.getId();

        /* logger2.dispose(); */

        ut.commit();
        // Thread.sleep(2000);

        while (status) {
            List<TaskSummary> taskSummaryList = JbpmAPIUtil
                    .getAssignedTasks(userName);
            for (TaskSummary taskSummary : taskSummaryList) {
                if (taskSummary.getName() == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (taskSummary.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("InitiatorTask")
                        && taskSummary.getProcessInstanceId() == processId) {
                    try {
                        JbpmAPIUtil
                                .completeTask(taskSummary.getId(),
                                        (Map) processData
                                                .get("projectFormDataMap"),
                                        userName);
                        status = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return processId;
}
```

When i execute this code it works fine on my end, all data is inserted into the tables.
But when created process is accessed to web panel it gives NPE at

```
ProjectFormData projectFormData=(ProjectFormData) process.getVariable("projectFormData");
System.out.println(projectFormData.getProjectFormDataMap()); <- NullPointer
```

I am stuck at this place from several days :( 
Please guys help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is probably related to differences in transaction demarcation.  More specifically, as long as a process instance is active within a transaction, it is 'connnected' to the process engine and will always be up-to-date and contain all internal information.  Once the transaction completes, process instances are 'disconnected' and contain a snapshot of the information as it was at the end of the transaction (acts as a DTO).

It seems here that the process instance you are getting the "projectFormData" variable from is now disconnected, and doesn't contain that variable (possibly because it's outdated?).

The solution could be either:
 - make sure you refresh your disconnected process instance somewhere right before this call (using ksession.getProcessInstance(..) to make sure you have the latest version
 - make sure to call getVariable(..) in the same transaction as where you got the process instance from, so it is still connected.

Comment: I have tried using it in single transaction but still what i have found that `projectFormData` is not getting saved in database as well. All the values in `processData` MAP are saved in processInstanceInfo except `projectFormData` and `rejectStatus`.
And this is the same code which is being used in web panel.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this NPE because some of the process variable you are trying to get are unavailable in processinstanceinfo table.
     process.getVariable("projectFormData");
Now this returns NULL because it is not getting saved in process variables may be be because some other method wants this to be some kind of filled object instead of just newwly instantiated object.